# Why extra space when \afterpage{} appears within a paragraph?

Tags: spacing, afterpage

For my dissertation, each figure must appear on its own page immediately following the page on which it is first referenced. The only way I have found to make this happen consistently is to do all of the following:

- Wrap each figure in `\afterpage{...\clearpage}`
- Use `\usepackage{flafter}`
- Define the float immediately after the first reference, even if that's in the middle of the paragraph.

But using `\afterpage{}` within a paragraph gives me extra space in the text where it appears. I'm hoping to learn either how I can avoid this extra space or how I can better achieve my float-placement needs.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
There is a normal amount of space after this sentence.
After this sentence is an afterpage placing ``test'' on the next page.
\afterpage{test}
Why is there extra space before this sentence?
\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image]

Comment: The extra space came from the newline after `\afterpage{test}`, which is converted to a space by tex. Commenting it does the work: `\afterpage{test}%`.

Comment: you are adding the space but I would ever use afterpage this way even though I wrote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of over using `afterpage` (note the warning in its documentation). Here I don't think you need it at all, just use `[p]` floats so they come on float pages not mixed with text and arrange that even small floats are shipped out early on their own page, not held back to collect more to fill more of the page.

In the first paragraph below I show the double space isn't really related to afterpage, You get th same with `{}` Conversely the `figure` environment is explicitly coded to be usable mid-paragraph and takes care to adjust the white space so if you leave space before it or after it only one space is added.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%  1 float per page, even if small
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0} 
\setlength\@fpsep{\textheight}
\makeatother
\showoutput
\begin{document}
There is a normal amount of space after this sentence.
After this sentence is an afterpage placing ``test'' on the next page.
See 0.
{}
Why is there extra space before this sentence?

There is a normal amount of space after this sentence.
After this sentence is an afterpage placing ``test'' on the next page.
See \ref{zzz}.
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \fbox{FFFFF}
  \caption{a figure}
  \label{zzz}
\end{figure}
Why is there extra space before this sentence?

There is a normal amount of space after this sentence.
After this sentence is an afterpage placing ``test'' on the next page.
See \ref{zzz2}.
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \fbox{GGGG}\\
  \fbox{GGGG}
  \caption{a notherfigure}
  \label{zzz2}
\end{figure}
Why is there extra space before this sentence?

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo that question is answered by the footnote on page one of `texdoc afterpage` :-)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, just [p] comined with the floatpagefraction setting do exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You has two spaces between the word `page.` and the word `Why`. The first space is from the end of the line 5 and the second is from the end of line 6. If you want only one space, you can do this by:

```
page.\afterpage{...} Why
```

or

```
page. \afterpage{...}Why
```

or

```
page.%
\aftepage{...}
Why
```

or

```
page.
\afterpage{...}%
Why
```

or

```
page.
\afterpage{...}Why
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this explains it, although it turns out I didn't really need afterpage.